# How to optimize BigQuery queries on a date field where most queries are at a year-month level

Tags: google-bigquery

A question about BigQuery query performance on date fields...

I have a very large data table where each record has an 'event date' field.  Most of the queries on the table are actually run at a calendar month level, e.g. January 2020 .  Is there any BigQuery performance gain to be had from having an extra field(s) that store either 'year-month' as one field or 'year' and 'month' as two separate extra fields?

Comment: date functions are relatively expensive but depends on how really large your table is  - you can see or not see improvement time wise. besides time cost (slots usage) can be decreased - but again - all depends on table size I think

Comment: 600 million records per year with 5 yeara worth of data

Answer (score 1):

Have you partitioned your table by month already, if not, doing so will allow the queries to scan much less data (only the specified month). The partition-by-month feature [went to GA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#September_21_2020) just weeks ago:

> September 21, 2020
>
> The following time-unit partitioning features are now Generally Available (GA):
>
> Creating partitions using hourly, monthly, and yearly time-unit granularities.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions#daily_partitioning_vs_hourly_partitioning